# VS Code does not change python environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, python-3.7

I am using VS-Code and anaconda environment for python interpreter. I select the exact anaconda base environment by **ctrl + shift + `** and it also reflects in the downside panel of vscode. But, when I checked the python version it shows **my system's default python environment 3.7.9**. If you see the below screenshot than, the **anaconda environment is with 3.8.3**.

Please give me solution, [image]Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To check & change vs code interpreter:

- In top left menu bar Click **view**
- In the dropdown menu, Click **Command Palette**
- Click **Python:** **Select Interpreter**
- Choose & Click on your desired Interpreter

Another way to be sure to use anconda interpreter, open **anaconda navigator** and launch **vs code** from there.

[original vs code How-To](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:%7E:text=To%20do%20so%2C%20open%20the,Settings%2C%20with%20the%20appropriate%20interpreter.)

Answer (score 5):

For those who have tried these steps:

- select different interpreter
- reboot VScode
- reinstall VScode Python extension and delete its folders

and have achieved nothing.

Probably **you are working in the workspace** and not in folder. You may have set interpreter at workspace level, which can't be used in one of the folders of the workspace. Try opening your folder separately from the workspace and select interpreter you want. This worked for me.

Comment: can someone clarify what exactly this means? "Try opening your folder separately from the workspace" Am I really unable to use a multi-folder workspace while setting the interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the version in VSCode does not change the the instance that your PS instance will use. Try doing where python to see where the V3.7.9 that your PS instance is picking up is. Then remove that version from the environment variables and add the path to the V3.8.3 instead.

Additionally you can do: To forcefully use v3.8.3

1. Specify python version in command

```
py -3.8 <command>
```

2. OR set PY_PYTHON environment variable to set which version to use.
   Take a look at this for further help [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#customizing-default-python-versions)

Comment: what do you mean by PS instance??

Answer (score 2):

after changing the environment, you  can restart the vs code again. it might be changed now. if not, then try changing now againg by clicking the interpreter name which is displayed on left bottom of the vscode window

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by changing the final step in the selection process:

The start is as usual:

- `Command Palette`
- `> Python: Select Interpreter`
- `+ Enter interpreter path`

but then, **not picking the option**

- `Find... Browse your file system to find a Python interpreter` (which opens a file explorer to select the interpreter)

but instead

- directly enter the full path in the text field and press Enter.

In theory, both should have the same effect, but for my case they did not. (I had tried reloading the window, restarting vscode, adding the venv to the known venv folders in the workspace settings, even recreating the venv in case something went wrong there, but none of these options worked.)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing worked from the above-suggested solution, you could try this.

Create a virtual environment in anaconda and activate it

```
conda create -n <environment_name> python=3.8.3

conda activate <environment_name>
```

Then you can directly open VS Code from same Anaconda terminal by typing

```
code
```

In the opened VS Code, you will see **python 3.8.3** will be activated. Instead of the default system **python 3.7.9**

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped to **uncheck** at User settings -> Extensions -> Python:

- Terminal: Activate Env In Current Terminal
- Terminal: Activate Environment

but I don`t know why.